# How to make my input field output exactly what's inputted?

Tags: php, html, input

I have an input field for uploading text to my site. I want to make it output exactly what's entered into it, without a single change. Currently, when someone presses enter, it's outputted as a space between the words. I want the words to be outputted on the page exactly how they exist in the input field. This is my code.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="HW">
            Write the assignment here.
            <br>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="70" name="txt">

            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Add homework" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where will the text be outputted? If the line break is the only character you need to change, you could do a search of the input on submit and just replace any line breaks with nothing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the end-of-line character with nothing, to effectively remove the line breaks.  An example of how to do this would look like:

```
$newString = str_replace("PHP_EOL", "", $oldString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nl2br()` PHP function if you want to save newlines.

Comment: I'm a beginner in PHP, so where exactly do I use that function in my code?